# Trying to get property 'POST /employee HTTP/1.1

Tags: php, laravel, forms, post

I have created a laravel application to store employee data, but when I submit the form it gives me the following error, what should I do to avoid this problem. thanks

[image: Error Exception]

This is my EmployeeController store method

```
    public function store(Request $request)
{
        $this->validate($request,array(
            'lastname'=>'required|max:60',
            'firstname'=>'required|max:60',
            'middlename'=>'required|max:60',
            'address'=>'required|max:120',
            'NIC'=>'required|max:10',
            'city_id'=>'required|max:60',
            'state_id'=>'required|max:60',
            'mobile'=>'required|max:10',
            'email'=>'required|max:60',
            'postal_code'=>'required|max:10',
            'birthdate'=>'required|date',
            'date_hired'=>'required|date',
            'department_id'=>'required|max:10',


    ));
    $employee = new Employee();
    $employee->lastname=$request->lastname;
    $employee->firstname=$request->firstname;
    $employee->middlename=$request->middlename;
    $employee->address=$request->address;
    $employee->NIC=$request->NIC;
    $employee->city_id=$request->city_id;
    $employee->state_id=$request->state_id;
    $employee->mobile=$request->mobile;
    $employee->email->$request->email;
    $employee->postal_code=$request->postal_code;
    $employee->birthdate=$request->birthdate;
    $employee->date_hired=$request->date_hired;
    $employee->department_id=$request->department_id;

    $employee->save();
}
```

Form header

```
{!! Form::open(['route'=>'employee.store','class'=>'form-horizontal p-t-20']) !!}
```

Classes i used for the controller

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Department;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use App\Employee;
```

Comment: Ah..I'm stupid. You need to validate `$request->all()` not `$request`

Comment: namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Department;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use App\Employee;

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is an error in your code.

```
   $employee->email->$request->email;
```

This should be,

```
   $employee->email = $request->email;
```

Answer (score 0):

By the looks of it you are trying to validate the `$request` variable itself. Hence the `Trying to get property POST`
Should it not be...

```
 $request->validate(array(
        'lastname'=>'required|max:60',
        'firstname'=>'required|max:60',
        'middlename'=>'required|max:60',
        'address'=>'required|max:120',
        'NIC'=>'required|max:10',
        'city_id'=>'required|max:60',
        'state_id'=>'required|max:60',
        'mobile'=>'required|max:10',
        'email'=>'required|max:60',
        'postal_code'=>'required|max:10',
        'birthdate'=>'required|date',
        'date_hired'=>'required|date',
        'department_id'=>'required|max:10',
));
```

Comment: That was not the issue. Both approaches are correct.

Comment: yes, i think nothing to worry about validations, i tried without validation but still im getting same error

Comment: Yeah sorry my bad, I'm not a Laravel dev just seen the `$request` var in the `validate` method and thought it didn't look right. Quick google search shows it is valid

Answer (score 0):

ErrorException: Trying to get property 'POST /Addpatients HTTP/1.1

> This ERROR IS DUE to

when you difine your variable in any method  Please check that you doest not define as below because it gives the error 
$patients->address->$request->input('address');

*The  solution is of this is as below*
$patients->address=$request->input('address');

Answer (score -1):

= not ->
in the email ! ( $employee -> email = $request -> email );

Comment: This is just a less clear version of the existing answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/52836927/1030169